# i want to hide fragment container view (Inside MainActivity Layout) from fragment but its not working when i click task button and then reopen app

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Activity mainActivity = getActivity();
    mFragmentViewContainer_MainActivity =  mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_containerView);
    mFragmentViewContainer_MainActivity.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

it works when i open app first time but **when i click on task button of android and then reopen app** **fragment container view became visible** again even

**i set visibility GONE inside OnResume**

Answer (score 0):

And don't really know if this work but try this !

In your fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private MyFragmentListener mCallback;

    public interface MyFragmentListener{
        public actionFromParent(int visibility);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NotNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mCallback = (MainActivity) context;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mCallback.actionFromParent(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

And your MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.MyFragmentListener {

    private View view;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
        
        view = findViewById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_containerView);
        
        // ...
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionFromParent(int visibility){
        view.setVisibility(visibility);
    }

}
```

I don't know if this is a good think to use set visibility from onResume. Better to use it with a button except if you know what are you doing.